# Backbone js auto refresh/reload collection from server and update view with collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

New to Backbone , please bear my not so beautiful backbone javascript code.

This is my code

```
var Schedule = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("initializing model");
    }
});

var ScheduleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Schedule,
    url: "<%=students_swimming_classschedules_path%>",
    parse: function (resp) {
        return resp;
    },
});

var Schedules = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("initializing view");
        collection.on('add', this.render, this);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            s += "<tr><td>" + collection.models[i].get('account') + "</td><td>" + collection.models[i].get('status') + "</td></tr>";
        }
        this.$el.html(s);
    },
})

var schedules = new Schedules({
    el: $("#students")
});

window.setInterval(function () {
    collection.fetch();

}, 2000);
```

This code works. And I can load all students to $('#students') container.

But I would like to auto reload the collection from server and the view every a few seconds. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You now need two more things:

First: Tell your view to update when collection is changes. This could be the revised version of your initialize function in your view.

```
initialize : function(){
  console.log("initializing view");
  collection.on('add', this.render, this);
  collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
  this.render();
},
```

this will refresh your view when new item is added to your collection. 
Note: this will re-render whole `#students` section. It's better if you write a separate method that will just inject the new item the DOM.

Second:
You need some way to fetch new data from server. As soon as you've received it, you just add them to your collection. You can use [fetch()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) methods of your collection like:

```
collection.fetch();
```

or, you can manually inject if you've received them using non-backbone ajax calls:

```
collection.add(newData);
```

As you wanted to delay few seconds between showing each load and show, you can use the [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) method from underscore library which is already a dependency for your backbone.

Comment: I have updated my code. Add `collection.on('add', this.render, this); `  and `window.setInterval(function(){
        collection.fetch();

}, 2000);` and removed these pre collection.add().  But how come the $("#students") not being loaded?

Comment: And I would like to reload everything in this collection not just add new items to collection

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I changed  `collection.on('add', this.render, this); ` with ` collection.on('sync', this.render, this); `

Comment: actually `fetch()` method triggers `reset` event. i'm sorry, i forgot to mention it in my answer.